# Sort the result after converting json to XML

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml

I have a json file like:

```
"files": {
    "audio": {
        "number1": {
            "enabled": false,
            "priority": 5,
        },
        "number2": {
            "enabled": false,
            "priority": 1,
        },
        "number3": {
            "enabled": false,
            "priority": 2,
        }
    }
}
```

I convert this json file to xml with some function and also this function:

```
function extractFile(data){

    // adding for loop to check priority number?

    var datas = [];
    var element = data.files.audio;

    datas.push({
        name : 'Num1',
        enabled : element. number1.enabled? "true":"false"
    });
    datas.push({
        name : 'Num2',
        enabled : element. number2.enabled? "true":"false"
    });
    datas.push({
        name : 'Num3',
        enabled : element. number3.enabled? "true":"false"
    });

    return datas;
}
```

The output is:

```
   <file name="Num1" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num2" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num3" enabled="false”/>
```

How can I order them based on the priority number in the json?

The output needs to be like:

```
   <file name="Num2" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num3" enabled="false"/>
   <file name="Num1" enabled="false”/>
```

Comment: Sort them before adding them to the `datas` array; you have what you need in `data`

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Thanks for the comment would you please answer it in the Answer field section with this:  function extractFile(data){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop in your code that can iterate over `data.files.audio` in an order. It seems like this is an object rather than an array so try [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) to create an array.

You will then need to sort the `data.files.audio` array using the answer to [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript).

**EDIT**

```
function extractFiles(data) {
    var elements = [];
    var files = [];

    // create an array of your source data objects
    for (var property in data.files.audio) {
        if (data.files.audio.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            var p = data.files.audio[property];
            p.name = property.toString();
            elements.push(p);
        }
    }

    // create function to sort object array by priority
    function compareFiles(a, b) {
        if (a.priority < b.priority) return -1;
        if (a.priority > b.priority) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    // create data for xml from sorted object array
    for (var e in elements.sort(compareFiles)) {
        files.push({
            name: elements[e].name,
            enabled: elements[e].enabled ? "true" : "false"
        });
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: @DaveAndersonThanks for the answer I saw different post on stackoverflow, would you please edit your answer with the exact code in function extractFile(data){  , I couldn't fix it and still have problem!

Comment: @Geremy so what problem did you have? I've included code for you but you should be trying to write this yourself if you want to learn.

Comment: @ DaveAnderson Thanks fixed it before and forgot to mark you answer , I had some misunderstanding by the way Thanks very much